# Spring service bean is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a simple Spring boot application that initialize a CLI game.

import com.rpg.game.rpggame.client.RpgGameClient;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RpgGameApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RpgGameApplication.class, args);
        RpgGameClient.runGame(); 
    }
}
```

The `runGame()` uses some of my services (spring beans).

```
public class RpgGameClient {

     @Autowired
     private static GameService gameService;

     public static void runGame() {
        gameService.createNewGame();
     }

  }
```

But I have a `NullPointerException` when using my service, since Spring can not successfully inject it on my `RpgGameClient` class.

How can I solve it?

Comment: where are you creating a bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `RpgGameClient` is not declared as a bean candidate.  So Spring ignores it.
You can do it by annotating the class with `@Component` for example (the simplest way) or by declaring a `@Bean` method that returns the instance of the class.

2) Even with that, it will not work still as `@Autowired` doesn't work for `static` fields. Spring injects dependencies into a bean and a bean is an *instance* of a class.
I think that `runGame()` should also be non `static`. Make all static for a bean spring makes no sense.   It is the same thing for the Spring boot application class.

3) Constructor injection should be favored to field injection.

So it should be better :

```
@Component
public class RpgGameClient {

     private GameService gameService;

     public RpgGameClient(GameService gameService){
       this.gameService = gameService;
     }

     public void runGame() {
        gameService.createNewGame();
     }

}
```

And change the Spring Boot app class to use injection dependency such as :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RpgGameApplication {

    @Autowired
    RpgGameClient rpgGameClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
       rpgGameClient.runGame(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RpgGameApplication.class, args);         
    }
}
```